# How to adjust spaces between words in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have large text file

if i want to make the spaces between words only 1 space

how could i do that?

because some of spaces are 2 or 3 or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr -s ' ' < input-file
```

will squeeze all strings of spaces to length one.